# C program to feed Cats and Dogs in a park

Tags: c

**Here is the problem I am trying to solve:**

To feed the cats and dogs in a park, you prepared D portions of dog food and C portions of cat food.

- There are a total of N animals waiting in a line, some of which are dogs and others are cats. It might be possible that all the animals in the line are dogs or all the animals are cats. A string S of N characters C and D represents the order of cats and dogs in the line. The i-th character is equal to C if the i-th animal in the line is a cat. Similarly, the i-th character is equal to D if the i-th animal in the line is a dog.
- The animals are fed in the order they stay in the line. Each dog eats exactly 1 portion of dog food and similarly each cat eats exactly 1 portion of cat food. Moreover, you have extra portions of cat food. Every time a dog eats food, you bring M extra portions of cat food for cats.
- Animals have to be fed in the order they wait in line and an animal can only eat if the animal before it has already eaten. That means that if you run out of dog (or cat) food portions and a dog (or a cat) is about to get fed, the line will not move, as all the animals will wait patiently.
- You need to determine if in this scenario all the dogs in the line will be fed. Note that this means that some cats might remain in the line, but worry not, you will eventually feed them later!

**Input:**

- The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow.
- The first line of each test case contains four integers N, D, C, and M: the number of animals, the initial number of dog food portions, the initial number of cat food portions, and the additional portions of cat food that we add after a dog eats a portion of dog food, respectively.
- The next line contains a string S of length N representing the arrangement of animals:

```
2
12 4 2 2
CDCCCDCCDCDC
8 2 1 3
DCCCCCDC
```

**Output:**

- For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is YES if all the dogs will be fed and NO otherwise.

Expected output for the input mentioned above:

```
Case #1: YES
Case #2: NO
```

**My problem:**
I keep getting YES for both test cases.

```
Case #1: YES
Case #2: YES
```

**My code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int T, N, D, C, M;
    char s[1000001];

    scanf("%d", &T);

    for (int i = 1; i <= T; ++i) {
        scanf("%d %d %d %d %s", &N, &D, &C, &M, s);

        int Dogs = 0;
        int Cats = 0;
        int DogsFed = 0;
        int CatsFed = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (s[j] == 'D') {
                Dogs++;
            }
            if (s[j] == 'C') {
                Cats++;
            }
        }

        while (C > 0 && (D > DogsFed || (D == DogsFed && s[N-1] == 'D'))) {
            for (int z = 0; z < N; z++) {
                if ((s[z] == 'D') && (D > 0)) {
                    DogsFed++;
                    D--;
                    if (M > 0) {
                        C += M;
                    }
                }

                else if ((s[z] == 'C') && (C >= (Cats-CatsFed))) {
                    CatsFed++;
                    C--;
                }
            }
        }

        if (DogsFed == Dogs) {
            printf("Case #%d: YES\n", i);
        } else {
            printf("Case #%d: NO\n", i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Feel free to ask any questions you may have.

Comment: You can never use `scanf()` correctly unless you ***Check The Return***... (applies to all input functions as well)

Comment: how do I check the return?

Comment: The `Xscanf()` family of functions returns the *Match-Count* for the conversion specifiers that were matched correctly during input. In your case `scanf("%d %d %d %d %s", &N, &D, &C, &M, s)` In your case there are 5 conversion specifiers, e.g. `%d %d %d %d %s"` so to properly check the return you use `if (scanf("%d %d %d %d %s", &N, &D, &C, &M, s) != 5) { /* handle the error */ }` (like removing all offending characters to the end-of-line, or calling `break` or `return 1` to exit, etc..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, `D` is "dog meals available" and the code is decrementing that variable while incrementing another: `DogsFed`... Then there's a whole lot of confused code attempting to calculate other numbers (that, quite frankly, I can't be bothered trying to follow.)

The loop conveniently breaks when `D == DogsFed` (lucky you that both test data samples had an even number for dogs to be fed!)

Use fewer variables that have **descriptive** names!

The following seems to work (with compile time data initialisation because laboriosly retyping data is tedious.) First get the code to work as you want, then modify it to accept user input (or input from a file.) And start to check the return codes from `scanf()`! User input could send your program off into the twilight zone if the user doesn't enter the appropriate data.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    // a struct to facilitate compile time initialisation of data
    typedef struct {
        int nDC, nDmeals, nCmeals, nExtraCatMeals;
        char *queue;
    } case_t;

    // OP sample data for 2 test cases
    case_t cases[] = {
        { 12, 4, 2, 2, "CDCCCDCCDCDC" },
        {  8, 2, 1, 3, "DCCCCCDC" },
    };

    // deal with each batch of sample data
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof cases/sizeof cases[0]; i++ ) {
        case_t *p = &cases[i];

        // Loop, hoping to reach end of the queue ("number of Dogs & Cats")
        int z = 0;
        while( z < p->nDC ) {
            switch( p->queue[z] ) {
                case 'D':
                    p->nDmeals -= 1; // dispense a dog meal
                    p->nCmeals += p->nExtraCatMeals; // load up on more
                    break;

                case 'C':
                    p->nCmeals -= 1; // dispense a cat meal
                    break;
            }
            // Break the loop if treading into unavailable meals.
            if( p->nDmeals < 0 || p->nCmeals < 0 ) // gone too far??
                break;
            z++;
        }
        // Yes/No as to feeding all the animals in the queue
        printf("Case #%d: %s\n", i+1, z == p->nDC ? "Yes" : "No" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Case #1: Yes
Case #2: No
```

Try to use the minimum number of variables that are required. Humans (readers) have a hard time keeping track of too many values, especially when some increase while others decrease...

---

**EDIT**
In keeping with the idea of fewer variables (for humans to track), the following is an alternative.

The day's "number of animals" is redundant and has been dropped. Each iteration, a cat is fed. If the iteration was, in fact, a dog, the cat is "unfed" and more cat meals are added.

Give this a try. Notice how easy it is to test with additional or modified data rows added to `days[]`. Less code (that performs correctly) is "better code" (imho).

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int DogMeals, CatMeals, CatPlus;
    char *pQ;
} day_t;

day_t days[] = {
    { 4, 2, 2, "CDCCCDCCDCDC" },
    { 2, 1, 3, "DCCCCCDC" },
    { 3, 1, 3, "DCCDCCDC" },
    { 3, 1, 1, "DCCDCCDC" },
};

int main( void ) {
    for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof days/sizeof days[0]; i++ ) {
        day_t *p = &days[i];
        do {
            p->CatMeals -= 1;
            if( *p->pQ == 'D' ) {
                p->DogMeals -= 1;
                p->CatMeals += 1 + p->CatPlus;
            }
        } while( p->DogMeals >= 0 && p->CatMeals >= 0 && *++p->pQ );

        printf( "Day %d: Unfed '%s'\n", i+1, p->pQ );
    }
    return 0;
}
```